# Open Source Equivalent of TFS?

Tags: .net, version-control, tfs, continuous-integration, tfs-workitem

Is there a combination of OSS which can be tightly integrated to perform the following?:

- Source Control (Preferably distributed, since we're not talking TFS. Currently thinking GIT.)
- Continous Integration (Currently thinking TeamCity, despite being a commercial product).
- Work Item Tracking (Really important for organised Agile development. The main advantage of TFS atm is the ability to relate check-ins to work items. I have no idea re. OSS on this one.)

To be honest, I've answered the first two myself. My main query is: does anyone know of a good work item tracker that can be tightly integrated into Source Control?

Comment: I hate posting Wiki links, but I just want to make sure that you've seen this comparison of source control systems. It might give you a place to start some research. You've probably already knocked most of these off your list though... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_revision_control_software

Comment: @Cory - Thanks for the link. It doesn't appear to mention Work Item Tracking though. I'm more looking for a suit of tools that can integrate together to replace TFS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org) as a project tracker.

It interfaces with a number of source control systems, Git being one of them, and monitors the commit messages for references to issues (it looks for things like "refs #123" and "fixes #123")  When you view an issue you'll see a list of source control revisions that were associated with the issue.  You can then click on the revision to see which files were affected and then see the changes made to each file.

If you are using Windows, then [TurtleMine](http://code.google.com/p/redmine-projects/) can be used to get a list of Redmine issues to associate with the commit.  This is a plug in for Tortoise products and I've used it with TortoiseSVN and TortoiseHg - I'd guess that it would work with TortoiseGit.

For me, the only downside with it is that it is quite difficult to install, but Bitnami have solved that issue by providing a number of easy to use [install options](http://bitnami.org/stack/redmine).